# PHP generar matriz de 2x2

Tags: php

debo de generar una matriz de 2X2, con cuatro numeros, y calcular cual es mayor y cual es menor... esto debo de hacerlo con php... saludos cordiales

```
introducir el código aquí



num($matriz);

function num($matriz){
    $numayor =array[0][0];
    $numenor = array[0][0];

    foreach ($matriz as $key) {
        if ($mayor < $key) {
            $mayor = $key;
        }
        if ($menor > $key) {
            $menor = $key;
        }
    }
}
 echo '"El numero mayor es"' ,$mayor;
?>
```

Comment: Soullith, lo que haces en tu foreach es comparar (por ejemplo) `$numayor` (debería ser `$numayor` que es la que declaras y no `$mayor`) con las filas enteras del array, y no con cada elemento de esas filas, por lo que necesitarías un doble bucle. Además, has hecho la función sin un `return` por lo que no devolverá nada

Answer (score 0):

Paso un código de ejemplo con el cálculo del mayor. El mismo código valdría para cualquier matriz BIdimensional. Y para perfeccionarlo, podría comprobarse si el resultado devuelve false, etc. Pero si la matriz es correcta seguro, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    $m = array(
            array(4,7),
            array(8,2)
        );
        
    function calculamayor($arr) {
        if (!is_array($arr)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!is_array($arr[0])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (is_array($arr[0][0])) {
            return false;
        }

        $resultado = $arr[0][0];
        foreach ($arr as $fila) {
            foreach($fila as $columna) {
                if ($resultado < $columna) {
                    $resultado = $columna;
                }
            }
        }
        return $resultado;
    }


    $mayor = calculamayor($m);
    echo ("El mayor del array es ".$mayor);
?>
```

Primero se revisa que sea un array bidimensional. Si no, se devuelve `false`. Después se recorren los elementos por filas y en cada fila, por columna.

Comment: En este ejemplo utilizo una función para calcular el mayor, y habría que hacer otra igual para calcular el menor. Si quieres hacer todo en la misma, una forma de resolverlo sería definir como resultado algo como `$resultado=array('mayor'=>$arr[0][0],'menor'=>$array[0][0]` y después hacer las comparaciones como `if ($resultado['mayor'] < $columna) {...` y un `return $resultado;` al final de la función.